# Switch audio device using winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, audio

i find this http://www.daveamenta.com/2011-05/programmatically-or-command-line-change-the-default-sound-playback-device-in-windows-7/ , and it works for me, but i want to switch audio devices, i have 2 audio devices, if active 1st turn on 2nd, if active 2nd turn on 1st. But i don't know is it possible to check if audio device active in windows

Answer (score 1):

The `IMMDeviceEnumerator` COM Interface used by the program you linked has a [GetDefaultAudioEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371401.aspx) method.

It returns an [IMMDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371395.aspx) interface pointer, the same type of interface pointer that the linked program gets while enumerating.